# C, "extern" type of variables in hardware abstraction layer

Tags: c, types, embedded, extern, hal

I am working on a Hardware Abstraction Layer. The aim of this HAL is to easily switch between the drivers for linux and the drivers for an MCU.

I am working on the SPI interface. Below is the signature of the function of the HAL that "open" the interface of SPI.

**hal/spi.h**

```
spi_handle_t spi_open(spi_port_t channel, spi_config_t config);
```

spi_port_t :

- On Linux, it is an elementary type : uint32_t
- On the MCU, it is a struct.

spi_config_t :

- On both Linux and the MCU it is a struct but with different fields.

So in **mcu/spi.c** I have at some point this :

```
typedef spiBASE_t spi_channel_t;
typedef spiDAT1_t spi_config_t;

spi_handle_t spi_open(spi_channel_t channel, spi_config_t config) {
.
.
.
}
```

And for **linux/spi.c** :

```
typedef uint32_t spi_channel_t;
typedef ChannelConfig_t spi_config_t;

spi_handle_t spi_open(spi_channel_t channel, spi_config_t config) {
.
.
.
}
```

Now the problem is in **hal/spi.h**, I need to define what is spi_channel_t and spi_config_t.

Is there a way to make something like (I know it is impossible with extern, but for explanation matters...) :

```
extern spi_channel_t;
extern spi_config_t;
```

This would say to the compiler : "Ok these two types are not defined in the header file, still you can find their storage size on one of the files I passed to the toolchain".

Comment: You *could* define the Linux 'native' types as structures with a single member. Would that work for you? Then your headers need only declare those types as `struct` ... so-called *opaque structures*. If that sounds good, maybe I can add more (as an answer, even).

Answer (score 6):

What you seem to be looking for is the trick called *opaque type*. It's a way to use *forward declaration* of structs in order to achieve private encapsulation and polymorphism in C. It is commonly used for professionally-written embedded systems drivers in particular and can be implemented like this:

**hal/spi.h**

```
// forward declaration of a struct, with typedef and struct tag:
typedef struct spi_handle_t spi_handle_t; 

// Require the caller to declare a spi_handle_t* pointer, not an object:
spi_handle_t* spi_init (...);
```

**mcu/spi.c**

```
struct spi_handle_t
{
  // whatever you need here - these are now 100% private members
};

spi_handle_t* spi_init (...)
{
  spi_handle* result = address_of_some_static_memory_pool;

  /* init struct members here */

  return result;  
}
```

**linux/spi.c**

```
struct spi_handle_t
{
  uint32_t something;
  // whatever you need here - these are now 100% private members
};

spi_handle_t* spi_init (...)
{
  spi_handle* result = malloc(sizeof *result); // malloc is fine to use in Linux

  /* init struct members here */

  return result;  
}
```

Now the caller will have to pass along the `spi_handle*` to other functions in the driver. This isn't just handy for OO design, but it also makes it possible to run the same code with multiple instances. For example if you have 2 different SPI hardware peripherals on the MCU and want to use them differently, but with the same driver code.

Comment: I didn't think of that option! +1

Comment: You can alternatively implement this with `typedef struct spi_handle_t* spi_handle_t;` and then get an API where objects seem to be passed by value, even though they are just pointers in disguise. I don't like hiding pointers behind typedefs personally, so I don't recommend that. I prefer to think that the user of my lib is a somewhat qualified C programmer and can therefore stand declaring pointers rather than objects in their code, if the library tells them to do so. It's a matter of style though, each style has its pros and cons.

Comment: Okay, I just took a deeper look and found that you are not refering to `spi_channel_t` and `spi_config_t` and it is not applicable on thos. This means that their type will always be incomplete anywhere you try to define an instance of the type to be given as an argument.

Comment: @eeucalyptus You'd have to implement them in the same manner, but in this case I really don't see why those shouldn't be private members of the struct. In the normal use-case, the user should set up stuff like baudrate, clock settings and channel once, and from there not mess around with them further.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Lundin ! In fact I applied your proposition on another project without knowing that. I could also apply this method for spi_channel_t and spi_confog_t but these two have a lot of fields on the MCU. So it is not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way of doing this would be to use the preprocessor in hal/spi.h:

```
#if defined(HAL_LINUX)
typedef uint32_t spi_port_t; /* int in linux */
#elif defined(HAL_MCU)
typedef struct {
    /* your struct in bare metal app */
} spi_port_t;
#else
#error "Platform not defined!"
#endif
```

You could also put the different types into different headers like `hal/spi_linux.h` and `hal/spi_mcu.h` and conditionally include one of them in `hal/spi.h`.

Alternatively, you could just take pointers and cast them to their actual type. This would be less safe because you would have to check the platform at runtime and decide the type behind the pointer, but this decision depends on many other things.

Comment: I thought about that idea too. But it requires creating an additionnal header. So I do not think I will apply this idea.