# Statements rather than expressions inside _Generic()

Tags: c, c11

I need to select statements rather than expressions inside `_Generic()`. I know I could put them inside a function, but I prefer to save a function call and use a macro instead. I know another possibility could be a GNU extension that converts statements into expressions, but I'd prefer not to use extensions if possible.

What I need is something like this:

```
#define FLOATWORK(X) do{ \
dostuff; \
dostuff; \
dostuff;}while(0)

#define DOUBLEWORK(X) do{ \
dostuff; \
dostuff; \
dostuff;}while(0)

#define GENERICWORK(X) _Generic((X), float: FLOATWORK(X), double: DOUBLEWORK(X))
```

Another possibility that came to my mind is to use the comma operator in my macros, trying to convert statements into an expression with the comma operator. However, I need a `switch/case` inside the macros, and a `switch/case` cannot be an expression AFAIK.

So, in conclusion, can I achieve this without putting the macro statements inside functions, and without using the GCC expressions statements extension?

Comment: You can use the ternary operator `?:` to create conditional expressions. You can nest them to get the equivalent of `switch/case`. It will be unreadable, but it might work.

Comment: You know function calls are pretty cheap, right?

Comment: You can always tell the compiler that you'd like the function to be inlined.

Comment: Yes, and if it can't be inlined, it is really not worth sacrificing readability and maintainability for the gain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C 2018 6.5.1.1 defines `_Generic` to take only expressions as operands. To use it to select statements, use a selection statement:

```
switch (_Generic(X, float: 0, double: 1))
{
    case 0:
       stuff;
       break;
    case 1:
       stuff;
       break;
}
```

This can be put into a macro as desired.

This results in the whole construction being a statement. Your question does not exclude that, but, if you want the entire construction to be an expression and the “stuff” you want to do is also expressions, then you can use the conditional operator:

```
_Generic(X, float: 0, double: 1) ? stuff : stuff;
```

Comment: Exactly. And since the value will be detected at compile time, all other cases will be optimized out, anyway.

Comment: I  decided to turn the macros into inline functions, though, as others suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a very good reason to use function-like macros, consider dropping those for normal functions instead. Then you can create `_Generic` macros to create type-generic function APIs. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float workf (float x)
{
  return x * 2.0f;
}

double worklf (double x)
{
  return x * 2.0f;
}

#define work(x) _Generic((x), float: workf, double: worklf)(x)

#define print(x) printf(_Generic((x), float: "%f\n", double: "%lf\n"), (x))

int main (void)
{
  float f = 1.0f;
  double d = 1.0;

  print(work(f));
  print(work(d));
  print(work(2.0f));
  print(work(2.0));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was using macros because the use is for passing floating point values as arguments to functions that belong to a virtual table of a generic-type interface: each "class" (actually `struct`, it's C and only C) is built for `float`, `double`, and `long double`, but however you need to invoke their methods using a unitary prototype: how do you make the methods for `float`, `double`, and `long double`, use the same interface? I decided to make the arguments of the virtual interface as tagged unions that can take any FP type. So, I chose macros for the getters/setters for the tagged union.

Comment: Now you understand why I need `switch/case`: The getter of the tagged union needs it. The setter can be done with a macro, though, as it can be done as two expressions separated by the comma operator.

Comment: (in fact the setter doesn't even need the comma operator: I'm doing it with a macro that generates a compound literal that builds an in-place argument for invoking the type-generic interface)

Comment: @cesss You could build such a "class" using the above method. Though in case different instances the "class" don't need to co-exist, a simple typedef would have solved everything much more elegantly. Or forward-declare an "opaque type" struct containing either a float, double or long double - that's how I usually implement polymorphism in C. See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65918357/584518).

Comment: Yes, they coexist because the user can choose the floating point precision at run time. I implemented this polymorphism by doing type-safe templates in C (achievable and type-safe if you do it with the `#include` technique, once for each type you want to instantiate, defining the template parameter `T` as the proper type in each instantiation). But then, at some point, you need a glue layer: the GUI code needs to be glued to the code of the instantiated templates. I chose a virtual table. But then, each function in the VT needs the same prototype: thus the tagged union came into the game.

Comment: @cesss Sounds far too needlessly complicated.

Comment: That's mainly because I didn't show the size of the code ;^) However, there's one part that I can improve in the future and that I learnt from the link you posted: using `typedef` inside a conditional definition for choosing the type for instantiating template code, rather than putting the type in a macro definition such as `T`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, because they need to be expressions. However, remember that you can use the comma operator and the ? : ternary operator and assignments to do many tricks:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FLOATWORK(X) (printf("hello "), printf("world\n"), 0)

#define DOUBLEWORK(X) (X == 5.0 ? printf("It equals 5\n") : \
                                  printf("It doesn't equal 5\n"), 1)

#define F(X) _Generic((X), float: FLOATWORK(X), double: DOUBLEWORK(X))

int main(void) {
    F(5.0f);
    F(5.0);
}
```